# How to do trigram / fuzzy match in neo4j cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, fuzzy-comparison

I was using postgreSQL which has show_trgam() and similarity(). I am new to neo4j and wanna do fuzzy comparison of two strings. It will be great if the comparison would return a score.

Any response is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no fuzzy comparison built into the query language. Perhaps you can explain your actual use-case. Perhaps there is another way of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your problem correctly.
You can use regular expression to compare values in neo4j.

Like

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*searchString.*'
RETURN n
```

It will return result with matching sub string.

You can have detail documentation about this here-
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#_regular_expressions